# How to find array index of largest value?

Tags: java, arrays

The title above sums up my question, to clarify things an example is:

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 3
array[2] = 7  // largest
array[3] = 5
```

so the result I would like is 2, since it contains the largest element 7.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the largest int in an array using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920353/how-to-find-the-largest-int-in-an-array-using-java)

Comment: This is a trivial thing to do actually. There are a lot of searching algorithms for this, have you even tried something?

Comment: Do you know how to sort an array?

Comment: there are simpler (and quicker) things than sorting...

Comment: Down-vote from me - I expect to see some effort on your part. This is not a difficult challenge.

Comment: Have you genuinely put efforts to solve this?

Comment: sorry I'm still pretty new to programming in general, its not an exact duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920353/how-to-find-the-largest-int-in-an-array-using-java) because I don't want to return the largest magnitude but the index of the largest magnitude. i'll go look at the answers now see if it works for me thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I locate and print the index of a max value in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991103/how-can-i-locate-and-print-the-index-of-a-max-value-in-an-array). Sadly I've used my close vote and retracted already, so can't kick the ball rolling. Can someone vote/flag?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public int getIndexOfLargest( int[] array )
{
  if ( array == null || array.length == 0 ) return -1; // null or empty

  int largest = 0;
  for ( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ )
  {
      if ( array[i] > array[largest] ) largest = i;
  }
  return largest; // position of the first largest found
}
```

Comment: You don't need to store `largest`.

Comment: @Duncan, true but it is a little more "readable" when you do ;)

Comment: Agree to disagree :-)  I think `indexOfLargest` would suffice as a single, self-explanatory variable.

Comment: @Duncan, but wouldn't that also be inefficient? You do a condition check + an assigned, regardless of whether the value is larger or not!?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. For the avoidance of doubt, this is what I'm suggesting (copy into IDE to format nicely!): `int indexOfLargest = 0; for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) { if ( array[i] > array[indexOfLargest] ) { indexOfLargest = i; }}`. Basically the same as [ifLoop's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22911823/474189).

Comment: Ok now that i get the solution i realised how simple it is :/ thanks nonetheless

Comment: @Duncan I would start the loop with `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 25):

```
int maxAt = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    maxAt = array[i] > array[maxAt] ? i : maxAt;
}
```

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for the hint, fixed this

Comment: @ifLoop, it's not fixed. The first iteration of the loop will crash with an exception (-1 out of range) ... edit: I see that you've corrected that now.

Comment: @Duncan, sorry I did get you and the author mixed up - my bad.

Comment: It might be neatest, if you would start your loop with `1` :) Also you can't differentiate between empty array and one element array.

Comment: As suggested by Boris, starting at one makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

one way will be:

```
 Integer[] array = new Integer[4];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 3;
    array[2] = 7;
    array[3] = 5;

    List<Integer> iList = Arrays.asList(array);
    System.out.println(iList.indexOf(Collections.max(iList)));
    System.out.println(iList.indexOf(Collections.min(iList)));
```

Comment: This does not find the index.

Comment: This is a nice solution if the array was already of `Integer`s. Sadly in many cases it's not and there isn't a pleasant way to move between the two (without external libs).

Comment: what if the values are repeatable.

Comment: If the values are repeatable the first occurence of index with repeated value will be considered.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int getIndexOfMax(int array[]) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return -1; // array contains no elements
    }
    int max = array[0];
    int pos = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (max < array[i]) {
            pos = i;
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 streams:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 7, 5);
    IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .reduce((i, j) -> list.get(i) > list.get(j) ? i : j)
            .getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two lines code will do that in efficient way

```
//find the maximum value using stream API of the java 8

Integer max =Arrays.stream(numbers) .max(Integer::compare).get();
// find the index of that value
int index  = Arrays.asList(numbers).indexOf(max);
```

Comment: The most elegant solution so far but due to Java streams implementation, not very efficient. C# does a better job with the IEnumerable interface implemented by arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below code for the same

```java
Integer array[] = new Integer[4];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 3;
array[2] = 7;
array[3] = 5;

List < Integer > numberList = Arrays.asList(array);

int index_maxNumber = numberList.indexOf(Collections.max(numberList));

System.out.println(index_maxNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another functional implementation

```
int array[] = new int[]{1,3,7,5};        

int maxIndex =IntStream.range(0,array.length)
              .boxed()
              .max(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> array[i]))
              .map(max->array[max])
              .orElse(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would do it like this (as I don't know any predefined function to get the index of highest element, only the element itself, of course you could get the index with `list.indexOf(element)` then, but array needs to be converted to list and 2 iterations):

```
maxIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[maxIndex]) {
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}
```