# How to find the tallest student (java)

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is my code so far:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] height = new int[5];
    String[] name = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Student "+(i+1)+" name: ");
        name[i] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Student "+(i+1)+" height: ");
        height[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I have the list of students, I have no idea how to find the tallest. Any suggestions. I can't think of anything, my mind is blank and I'm really struggling with this. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You have the array with all the students' heights. This is a little hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911722/how-to-find-array-index-of-largest-value/22911923

Comment: Note that you have something called _parallel arrays_, which are a major red flag in design. Instead, the better way is to create a `class Student` with `height` and `name` and use `Student[]` (or better, `List<Student>`).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use a loop, keeping track of the index of the current tallest student.

```
int maxIdx = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) 
     if(height[i] > height[maxIdx]) maxIdx = i;
System.out.println("Index = " + maxIdx + ", height = " + height[maxIdx] 
    + ", name = " + name[maxIdx]);
```

`Stream#max` could also be used.

```
int maxIdx = IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed()
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> height[i])).get();
System.out.println("Index = " + maxIdx + ", height = " + height[maxIdx] 
    + ", name = " + name[maxIdx]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple logic is to use a HashMap to map student names with their heights and then sort the heights. Once you sort, you can easily get the largest height and find the students with that height using the HashMap

Reference for Map: [https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map#:~:text=%E2%86%92%20%E2%86%90%20prev-,Java%20Map%20Interface,the%20basis%20of%20a%20key](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map#:%7E:text=%E2%86%92%20%E2%86%90%20prev-,Java%20Map%20Interface,the%20basis%20of%20a%20key).

Code:

```
//Import necessary Java libraries. I'll leave it to you to explore imports.

Map map = new HashMap();

// Register values. (Name, Height) format
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    map.put(name[i], height[i]);
}

//Sort height
Arrays.sort(height);

// Get Maximum height
int maxHeight = height[height.length - 1];

// Find the names with this height.
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       if (entry.getValue() == maxHeight) {
             System.out.println(entry.getKey());
         }
   }
```